# Difference between two loops

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

The code below is the correct, working solution to an exercise I had to work out. I am wondering why my solution did not work.

The only difference I had was this line:

`for (var i = contacts.length; i > 0; i--) {`

Why it did not do the same just reversed direction?

```
for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName == name){
        if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            return contacts[i][prop];
        } else{
            return "No such property";
        }
    }
}
return "No such contact";
```

Comment: In the working version, the loop body is run when `i` is zero; in your version, it isn't.

Comment: There's no element with index `contacts.length`

Comment: Try with `var i = contacts.length - 1` and `i >= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code.

- the first problem is that you start i = contacts.length and as you know there is no element in the array at the array length position
  because arrays go from 0 to array.length-1.
  **the solution for that problem is var i = contacts.length - 1.**
- the second problem is that i never goes to zero because your stop condition is i > 0
  then you never reach the first element of the array. 
  **the solution is changing the stop condition to i >= 0**

Answer (score 1):

The two loops have different ranges.

If `contacts.length` had equalled `4`, then `i` would have taken on these values:

```js
console.log('ascending loop');
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {console.log(i);}
console.log('descending loop');
for (var i = 4; i > 0; i--) {console.log(i);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Array Start with 0.
Length Start with 1.

let say i want the last element from contact array

```
let contact = ['mo','so','do'];
console.log(contact[length])
```

It won't show a console. Y ? Because To get a last array.
You always need to `-1` from the array.length

Answer (score 0):

On the answer, the for counter go like 0 ... n, and on your for loop, the counter goes like n ... 1.

So, on your code, the index never is 0